# How to append list of objects in serialized data? in Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have following output currently.

```
{
    "carts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "description": null,
            "default": "Yes"
        }
    ],
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Indoor Muscle Training",
            "description": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Outdoor Muscle Training",
            "description": null
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to append few list of objects like below. These product need to be static right now.

```
{
        "carts": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "product_id": 1,
                "description": null,
                "default": "Yes"
            }
        ],
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Indoor Muscle Training",
                "description": null,
                "products":[
                 { 
                    "id":1,
                    "name":"Product One"
                 },
                 { 
                    "id":2,
                    "name":"Product Two"
                 }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Outdoor Muscle Training",
                "description": null,
                "products":[
                 { 
                    "id":1,
                    "name":"Product One"
                 },
                 { 
                    "id":2,
                    "name":"Product Two"
                 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here's my current files
views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        default_cart = DefaultCart.objects.all()
        categories = Category.objects.filter(parent_id=0)
        serialized_default_cart = DefaultCartSerializer(default_cart, many=True)
        serialized_categories = CategorySerializer(categories, many=True)
        return Response({
            'carts':serialized_default_cart.data,
            'categories':serialized_categories.data,
        })
```

serializers.py

```
class DefaultCartSerializer(serializers. HyperlinkedModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:        
        model = DefaultCart        
        fields = (
            'id',
            'product_id',
            'description',
            'default'
        )   

class CategorySerializer(serializers. HyperlinkedModelSerializer):   
    class Meta:        
        model = Category        
        fields = (
            'id', 
            'name', 
            'description',
        )
```

These products need to be append a static values right now. Later I will apply nested serializer by defining many-to-many relationship between product and category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **SerializerMethodField**:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers. HyperlinkedModelSerializer):   
    products = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:        
        model = Category        
        fields = (
            'id', 
            'name', 
            'description',
            'products'
        )   

    def get_products(self, obj):
        return [
             { 
                "id":1,
                "name":"Product One"
             },
             { 
                "id":2,
                "name":"Product Two"
             }
        ]
```